# Is it possible to declare a function inside GSP?

Tags: groovy, jsp-tags, gsp

How can I declare a function inside GSP? I need something like taglib but declared inside GSP - it doesn't matter outside

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't define methods in GSPs. But you can have anonymous functions if you want :D

Example:

```
<%
    def prettify = { "***$it***" }
%>
<h1>${prettify(someText)}</h1>
```

Though this example doesn't make too much sense, as that little formatting could be inlined. For any kind of extra logic for the views, I would follow [OverZealous recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173475/581845) and use a taglib.

Comment: I agree that in most cases a Taglib (or a sub-template called with `g:render`) are the correct solutions. But sometimes there's a tiny bit of repeated logic that it's good to write only once in a GSP, but doesn't warrant such a promotion to an external file. In those cases, I like to write it like this: `<g:set var="greet" value="${{it =~ /^Mr\./ ? it : "Mr. $it"}}"/>` Notice the double curlies `{{}}` that define a closure. You then use it like a regular function: `${greet("Sam")}`

Answer (score 6):

No. Just don't do this. This is completely against the purpose of a GSP. The GSP is designed to handle visual markup information, not programming logic. Throwing functions directly within your GSP **will** lead to an unmaintainable mess of code.

Why won't you put it in a tag?  This is what tags are for; it doesn't matter that it is only used within your GSP.  The GSP should only contain simple display logic and output content.  Reusable code should always be contained within a taglib or in some sort of controller or service for complex logic.

You don't mention what framework you are using, such as Gaelyk or Grails.  (Unless you are using pure Groovy on the server for some reason.)  There's no practical way to recommend a good solution here without more information.

If you are using JSP-style tags (`<% %>`) in your GSP, you are probably doing it wrong.

If you want a better answer, please provide more detailed information about the programming environment, what the goal is, and why (for why you don't want to use a taglib).

Comment: Suppose I have template for row. This template doesn't metter outside this GSP. Is it possible to declare template inside GSP?

Comment: I would use `<g:each collection="${collection}" var="item"> TEMPLATE HERE </g:each>`

Comment: could be useful for a small inner template, like a hierarchy.

Comment: @fedor.belov A sub-template should be kept in its own file with a leading underscore, such as `_header.gsp`, and invoked with `<g:render template="header" model="[...]">` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903353/is-there-a-way-to-do-gsp-partials-rather-than-tag-libraries#comment48785670_2903445